# Why I have bad screen resolution in bios on my laptop?

Tags: linux, video, bios, resolution, bootloader

I have a bit boring problem: When I am trying to install any os on my laptop or use any bootloader, what using only bios output without more drivers, I always get bad screen resolution. (After installing os + drivers everything is normal, but not bios - surprisingly).

[image: screenshot1]
[image]

I need to have 1600x900 in Grup bootloader or Clover bootloader. I tried lot of things, but not success.

Here is some specs:

```
root@kali:~# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               876.428
CPU max MHz:           3100,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              4385.94
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts

root@kali:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
03:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1009 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)

root@kali:~# hwinfo --short
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 1420 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 1322 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 975 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 933 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 870 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 1214 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 860 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz, 970 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event1    A4Tech USB Device
  /dev/input/event0    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      A4Tech USB Device
  /dev/input/mice      AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint
monitor:
                       CVW69 173WD1 LCD Monitor
graphics card:
                       Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
                       nVidia GF108M [GeForce GT 525M]
sound:
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
storage:
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
network:
  eth0                 Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  wlan0                Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN
network interface:
  wlan0                WLAN network interface
  eth0                 Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             Crucial_CT275MX3
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/sda5            Partition
cdrom:
  /dev/sr0             MATSHITA DVD+-RW UJ8C1
usb controller:
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
                       Fresco Logic FL1009 USB 3.0 Host Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
                       Intel HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
                       Intel Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Intel Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Intel Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       PS/2 Controller
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
                       Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
                       Sunplus Innovation Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD
  /dev/input/event3    A4Tech USB Device
                       Validity Sensors VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
```

**Model:** Dell Vostro 3750 (i7)

**Bios:** Phoenix Secure Core Tiano

**Graphics card:** Intel HD 3000 (+ Nvidia 525m)

Any ideas where can be I problem?
Also I got this laptop with bad screen resolution as default, but it is totally upsets me.
So, how to change this defaults to normal 1600x900 resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it would be possible for you. See, BIOS (and bootloaders are also displayed using BIOS commands usually) supports only basic resolution, usually VGA ones (or it's subsets, such as XGA, rarely more than that, you can read about it here for example: [VGA Resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#Video_Graphics_Array)).

1600x900 is neither VGA resolution or XGA one. Well, basically it's a "kind of" non-standart resolution, so BIOS won't support it.

In the running OS, the Graphics Driver takes the control from BIOS, and manages to switch the graphic card in any resolution it wants, but BIOS have just a list of predefined ones.

Comment: **Yes thanks!** But is there any way to fix it? Like patching BIOS? I know that this can cause problems, but I need it, because looking every day to Grup bootloader with bad resolution is totally boring. (yes boring)

Comment: Well it's either supported or not, there is not much you can do unless you're a BIOS guru who can reprogram it. :) You can check all the availables resolution by installing a utility called vesafb - it will show which resolutions it can enable during boot-time (when BIOS manages it), and so you can configure GRUB to use one of them. More info can be found here, for example: [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=258484). Please note that won't allow you to change the resolution in BIOS menu itself, because it's hard-coded in BIOS firmware.

Comment: Yep. That's good answer! After twenty hours I will add bounty, because - You can add bounty after 23 hours.

Comment: Basically the supported in BIOS resolutions are defined mostly by VESA BIOS extensions - you can read more about supported modes here: [available modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Other_commonly_available_graphics_modes)

Comment: Also the command from Linux `hwinfo --framebuffer` will show you all the available modes.